# How to know action (HTTP method) type in DRF generic views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When using `ViewSet`s you can do `self.action` and get to know whether you are currently handling a `GET` or `POST` and such. How do you do the same with generic views like `ListCreateAPIView`?

I want to return a different serializer context in `get_serializer_context` depending on the current HTTP method being called. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `self.request.method`

```py
def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.request.method)
    # rest of your code
```